data: { message: '401: Unauthorized', code: 0 } error on discord oauth2
I'm trying to use the guilds.join oauth2 scope to join my alts test server. I currently have the following code but I keep getting 401: Unauthorized error. I've attempted to remove the userinfo variable but that did nothing. If anyone knows how to fix it please let me know.
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const url = require('url');

const port = process.env.PORT || 1500;
const app = express();

app.get('/api/auth/discord/redirect', async (req, res) => {
    const { code } = req.query;

    if (code) {
        const formData = new url.URLSearchParams({
            client_id: process.env.ClientID,
            client_secret: process.env.ClientSecret,
            grant_type: 'authorization_code',
            code: code.toString(),
            redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:1500/api/auth/discord/redirect',
        })

        const output = await axios.post("https://discord.com/api/v10/oauth2/token",
            formData, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                }
        });

        if (output.data) {
            if (output.data.error) {
                console.error("Error:", output.data.error);
            } else {
                const access = output.data.access_token;
                console.log(access);
                const userinfo = await axios.get('https://discord.com/api/v10/users/@me', {
                    headers: {
                        "Authorization": `Bearer ${access}`,
                    }
                });
                userid = userinfo.data.id
                await axios.put(`https://discord.com/api/v10/guilds/REMOVEDFORPRIVACY/members/${userid}`, {}, {
                    headers: {
                        "Authorization": `Bearer ${access}`,
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    }
                })
                console.log("User Name:", userinfo.data.username)
                console.log("User ID:", userinfo.data.id)
                
            }
        } else if (output.data.errors) {
            console.error("Error:", output.data.errors.access_token);
        }
    
            
        
    }
});

app.listen(port, () => {console.log(`Running on ${port}`)});

I've tried removing the identify but that didn;t work.
